# Cannot access my website with the custom domain name when using VPN

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpn, amazon-route53

I developed a website and deployed it using EC2 on AWS and redirected the domain name which I bought from domain.com to the EC2 IP address with Route 53. The site is accessible when I'm not using VPN. However, when I start using the VPN, I cannot access the website and redirect to a page that shows the site is under development. How can I fix this problem? Many thanks!! 
[The picture is the records of my R53 hosted zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOoZZ.png) 
I also have added the values which generate by the AWS to the nameservers of domain.com. The domain name was bought last year and started using it from June.

Information of ip and nslookup:
(1) website ip: 18.222.135.126
(2) domain name: weiyipeng.com
(3) nslookup with VPN off: 18.222.135.126
(4) nslookup with VPN on: 240.0.0.6

Comment: Hard to say with the information provided. Can you please edit your post to include 1) The domain name 2) Website IP 3) nslookup of the domain without the VPN 4) nslookup with the VPN turned on. If you do all that you might work the answer out yourself, if you do please answer your own question below.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the comment. I update the post with the information you required. Apparently, the nslookup with VPN on map to a reserved ip address.

Comment: Oddly enough, when I use mxtoolbox to search for your website the IP returned is 66.96.162.130 ( https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3aweiyipeng.com&run=toolpage ). Something odd is happening with your DNS. I suggest you look into DNS, if you need help update your post with as much info as you can, particularly which servers are being queried for DNS, then comment if you want me to know the post has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain.com set two extra nameservers in default, which are serve in Europe and Asia. When I use the VPN based in Europe it will map to the domain.com nameserver which nslookup is start with 66.*. After I delete these two nameservers, everythings work fine. Thanks to Tim for the hints.

Comment: Good to see you worked it out :)